# High-side, low-side pressure readings slow to equalize after turning AC off

Tags: ac, measurement, refrigerant

I was helping a friend yesterday with their E53 X5's AC system when I noticed this strange behavior:

- Before turning the AC on for the first time both high-side and low-side pressures read the same
- After turning the AC on the high-side pressure reading went higher and low-side went lower (as expected)
- After adding some refrigerant via the low-side charging port and turning the AC off the high-side and low-side pressures did not equalize immediately as I have seen it do on other vehicles. After 2-3 minutes there was still a healthy 60 psi difference in the two readings

Is this behavior indicative of something? A clogged expansion valve, perhaps?

Comment: Check expansion valve

Comment: If the system was cooling then expansion valve can’t be clogged ...

Comment: Has it got rear AC?

Comment: I have to confirm, but I believe it does

Comment: Cars that recent, with such big AC systems, usually feature solenoid valves to shut the flow to both front and rear. Especially with the newest electronically controlled variable displacement compressors (with buses, usually featuring a very large fixed displacement compressor for the entire bus and no separate compressor for the driver, passenger AC has to be turned on before driver AC can, instead). That way, equalization won't happen. Equalization may make liquid from the condenser travel into the compressor and immediately slug it at startup.

Comment: @Al_ The car does have rear AC but it doesn't work. Also, this vehicle was cooling the driver side only prior to the recharge. Now both driver and passenger side cool. I'm not sure if it qualifies as a large AC system as it requires just 440 g R-134a

Comment: Newer systems work with higher efficiency (which can also mean lower lubricant charge, esp. with scroll and vane compressors) and lower refrigerant charges than older ones (that's also why they lose their cooling capacity faster compared to R-12 systems) - environmental reasons. Refrigerant is best never added: it should be reclaimed and then the original charge put inside after vacuuming for a long time (along with any reclaimed oil).

Comment: I'll second that recommendation.